# Term for organization being sponsored — "sponsee"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, is-it-a-word, legalese

I have seen a few sponsorship agreements and in one of them the term "sponsee" was used to define the organization being sponsored.

The context was a company who sponsors a local team. The agreement specifies the sponsor's benefits (advertising on the team's shirt, etc) and the sponsor obligations (providing X amount of money, support...).

Is this an actual word? If not, please provide me with alternatives.

Comment: Interesting. I'm on a soccer team that is sponsored by a local bar. I was unaware that lawyers were typically involved in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a common term ([Ngram - sponsor vs sponsee](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sponsor%2Csponsee&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csponsor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csponsee%3B%2Cc0) ) but it is increasingly used ([Ngram - sponsee](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sponsee&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csponsee%3B%2Cc0)) since the 80's.

[Sponsee](http://www.yourdictionary.com/sponsee): (from www.yourdictionary.com)

> - Noun(plural sponsees) One who is sponsored.

If you don't feel comfortable with this term you can use, 'the sponsored team'.